# Prove $\lim_{n \to\infty} \sigma_{N} = \lim_{N \to\infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n = a$ if $ \lim a_n = a$

Tags: real-analysis

As stated, if $\{a\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}$, prove $$\lim_{n \to\infty} \sigma_{N} = \lim_{N \to\infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n = a$$

Not sure how to begin with this.  I know $\sum a_n$ won't converge unless $a=0$.  It also seems to me that $\lim_{n \to\infty} \sigma_{N} = 0 + 0 + ... + 0$ since $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, which I know can't be right.

Thank you!

Comment: Why does $a$ need to be $0$?

Comment: From Rudin: If $\sum a_n$ converges, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$

Comment: But you have $\frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N \to a$, not $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \to a$.

Comment: Right, I'm not saying that $\sigma_N$ won't converge if $a \neq 0$, just that $\sum a_n$ won't converge.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with $\sum a_n$ converging.

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to state some things I know

Comment: @AliceCao Umberto P. is (correctly) pointing out that you are referring to a different thing. Saying that the quantity $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ converges (by the mean, it's called the Cesaro mean) has *nothing* to do with the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ being convergent.

Comment: In particular, if you take $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1 \neq 0$, **and** $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = \frac{1}{n}\cdot n = 1 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1 = a$. But $a\neq 0$. So the fact you state (for converging series) is not relevant nor helpful for your question (about Cesaro mean).

Comment: Instead, you can work using the definition of convergence: by assumption, for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N_\varepsilon$ such that $$\forall n \geq N_\varepsilon,\qquad |a_n - a| \leq \varepsilon\,.$$ Now, you can write, for $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, $$|\sigma_n - a| = \left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n -a \right| = \left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_n -a) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{N_\varepsilon} |a_n -a| +  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N_\varepsilon}^n |a_n -a|$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n= \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{a_n}N$ and $\frac{a_n}N \to 0$ therefore there is not contradiction here.

Comment: @gimusi Even your comment does not fall into the "converging series must have term going to zero" result (so it's just making things more confusing). Since with your rewriting, well, the general term depends on $N$, so it doesn't even define a valid series (what is $a_n$ in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?)

Comment: @OP you accept the answer you want, of course, but... you accepted the one "proving" your result by *invoking the theorem which states the generalization of the result you wanted to prove*? That's very circular.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes you are right that argument is not correct. We can observe that since $a_n \to a$ eventually for some $\bar N$ $\exists k>0$ such that $|a_n|<k$ and therefore we have $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = \bar N}^{N} |a_n| \le \sum_{n = \bar N}^{N} k=\frac{N-\bar N +1}{N}k \to k$.

Comment: @ClementC. Regarsing the proof, the idea fro my answer is to prove a more general result, for which I gave a link with the proof, to prove a minor result as a corollary. Nothing wrong here, it is only a matter of preference.

Comment: @gimusi That's my point. Your answer invokes the theorem, doesn't prove it.

Comment: @ClementC. I could copy the prove form the link or from my notes but I really think it is not useful here.

Comment: @gimusi To you, no. But to the OP? It's like you had answered the question "How do I prove this result?" by "it follows from the Cesaro theorem, since it's the exact statement of it." Good to know, but knowing *how to prove it* is the point.

Comment: @ClementC. I suppose that the OP can evaluate by him/herself what is good for an answer. You are correct to express your thought about it but you should accept different points of view on that. I understand your point and the OP is free to change answer if another one fullfil better his/her requirements. Cheers

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, the result, also known as Cauchy's first theorem, is  a particular case of [**Stolz-Cesaro**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Stolz-Ces%C3%A0ro_Theorem) theorem indeed by

$$b_N=\sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n \quad c_N=N$$

we have that

$$\frac{b_{N+1}-b_N}{c_{N+1}-c_N}=\frac{\sum_{n = 1}^{N+1} a_n-\sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n}{N+1-N}=a_{N+1}\to a$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{N \to\infty}\frac{b_N}{c_N}=\lim_{N \to\infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n = a$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard
good-part bad-part proof.

Since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n
=a$,
for any $c > 0$
there is a $n_c$ such that
$|a_n - a| < c$
for $n > n_c$.
This is the good part,
and the others
$(n \le n_c$)
make up the bad part.
Since the good part can be
arbitrarily large,
it dominates so
the bad part can be ignored.

Here are the details.

If
$s_{N} 
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n
$
then,
for any $c > 0$,
there is a $n_c$ such that
$|a_n-a| < c$
for $n > n_c$.

Then,
with multiple uses
of the triangle inequality,

$\begin{array}\\
s_{N}-a 
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n-a\\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} (a_n-a)\\
&= \frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{n_c} (a_n-a)+\sum_{n = n_c}^{N} (a_n-a)\right)\\
\text{so}\\
|s_{N}-a| 
&= |\frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{n_c} (a_n-a)+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = n_c}^{N} (a_n-a)\right)|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{n_c} (a_n-a)|+|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = n_c}^{N} (a_n-a)|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{n_c} (a_n-a)|+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = n_c}^{N} |a_n-a|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{N} d(n_c)|+|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = n_c}^{N} c|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{N} d(n_c)|+|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N} c|\\
&= |\frac{1}{N} d(n_c)|+c\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$d(n_c)$ is independent of $N$,
by making 
$\frac{1}{N} d(n_c) < c$,
or
$N > \frac{d(n_c)}{c}$,
we get
$|s_N-a|
< 2c$.

Now choose
$c = \epsilon/2$
and we are done.